# grid-row span is not working without break point

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i was working on a image gallery and what i was trying to do is to make some images wider and some taller and this is my code and when i try to span two lines horizontally it works but vertically nothing changes

```
my HTML code

  <div id="img">
        <div class="tal"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="wide"></div>
        <div class="big"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="tal"></div>
        <div class="wide"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="big"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="tal"></div>
        <div class="big"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="big"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="wide"></div>
        <div class="big"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="tal"></div>
    </div>
my CSS code 

#img {
    background: rgb(201, 201, 201);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px,1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#img .tal {
    background: lime;
    grid-row: span 2;
}

#img .wide {
    background: rgb(2, 2, 70);
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added padding to your code to see the effect and I find that cells spans vertically and horizontally correct.
If your desired result is different please illustrate it and share the illustration with an edit to your post

```css
div{
  padding: 30px;
}
#img {
  background: rgb(201, 201, 201);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column: 1/5;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#img .tal {
  background: lime;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

#img .wide {
  background: rgb(2, 2, 70);
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
  <div class="tal"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="tal"></div>
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="tal"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="tal"></div>
</div>
```